# AngularDart on Firefox fails with "receiver.webkitCreateShadowRoot is undefined"

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I have an AngularDart application that is working fine on Chromium and Chrome with Javascript. But in Firefox and IE, I get the following error:

```
[14:36:14.648] "NullError: receiver.webkitCreateShadowRoot is undefined

STACKTRACE:
.Element.createShadowRoot$0@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:84445
J.createShadowRoot$0$x@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:153659
._ComponentFactory.call$6@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:11337
.BlockFactory__instantiateDirectives__closure2.call$1@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:11097
.Primitives_applyFunction@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:5148
._FactoryProvider.get$2@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:125034
J.get$2$x@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:153716
.DynamicInjector__getInstanceBySymbol_closure.call$0@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:124806
._defaultCreationStrategy@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:125162
.Binding.creationStrategy$3@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:125271
.DynamicInjector._getInstanceBySymbol$2@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:124652
.DynamicInjector.get$1@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:124694
J.get$1$x@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:153713
.BlockFactory__instantiateDirectives_closure3.call$1@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:11183
.IterableMixinWorkaround_forEach@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:22126
.JSArray.forEach$1@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:1995
J.forEach$1$ax@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:153707
.BlockFactory._instantiateDirectives$5@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:10887
.BlockFactory._dom$_link$4@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:10816
.BlockFactory._dom$_link$4@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:10818
.BlockFactory._dom$_link$4@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:10818
.BlockFactory._dom$_link$4@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:10818
.BlockFactory.call$2@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:10776
.ngBootstrap_closure0.call$0@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:7661
._rootRun@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:27183
._ZoneDelegate.run$2@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:34652
.NgZone__onRun_closure.call$0@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:10306
.NgZone._onRunBase$4@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:10162
.NgZone._onRun$4@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:10181
$$.BoundClosure$4<.call$4@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:424
._ZoneDelegate.run$2@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:34652
._CustomizedZone.run$1@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:35046
.ngBootstrap@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:7485
.main@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:130170
._IsolateContext.eval$1@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:3635
.startRootIsolate@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:3301
@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:161315
@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:161295
@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:161309
@http://127.0.0.1:3030/foobarUI/web/foobarui.dart.js:9
"
```

Here is my foobarUI/pubspec.yaml:

```
name: foobarUI
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  angular: 0.9.3
  browser: any
  json_object: any
  petitparser: any
  unittest: any
  foobar:
    path: ../foobarLib
```

I tried to add the js, shadow_dom and web_ui modules but it made no difference.

I tried to add "useShadowDom = true;" (and false) to the main dart file, no difference.

From the error, it seems obvious that the webkit support for DOM shadow root is missing but why is this module not handling this ?

The same error occurs with angular.dart.tutorial chapter_03 sample. This is clearly an issue with Angular.Dart. Bug filed as: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dart bug for issue is at: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15144

It has been fixed in Dart bug has not been pushed to AngularDart yet.  That work is blocked by  https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/366.

Comment: This issue was indeed fixed in Dart 1.1 and it is now working properly in Firefox 27, Safari 7 and IE10. It is still not working with IE8 but I think I'll have to live with it.